Is there any method to create of an instance of structure which is inside a class in the main function in c++?
Actually, I could have phrased it correctly the first time, but what I meant to ask is Whether there is a way to create an instance of the structure, similar to how the instance and a objects are created within the class, directly in the main function in C++
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ABC {
    private:
        
        string name, f_name, session, cls, dob;

    public:
        
        struct elephant {
            string x, y, z;
        };

        elephant instance;

        elephant a;

        ABC() {
            cout << "the default constructor" << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
   ABC i;
   i.instance.x= "We";
   return 0;
}

I was trying to create an instance of structure which is in class.

This compiles. What is your question?

Do you want to initialize instance in ABC's constructor or in main ?

ABC::elephant dumbo{};?

A side note: What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.

"I was trying to create an instance of structure which is in class" - How did you try it and what happened? Please show the full error message if you got one.

An instance is created by your code. It is just not initialized

I think I was too hasty to graduate the question from the staging ground ...

Your code already creates an object of type ABC::elephant - when creating i, i.instance is created as a part of i (it is not possible to create an instance of ABC without also creating its member named instance.

Is there a way to create an instance of the structure, similar to how the instance and a objects are created within the class?"

@IgnatiusKhan please [edit] your question and clarify what you need (instead of in a comment).

Q:  Can you directly create an instance of a struct (or class) that's defined inside another struct (or class) without creating an instance of the outer struct (or class)?
A:  Yes, as long as the definition of the inner struct is accessible by the code that wants to instantiate it.
Since elephant is defined as a public type in ABC, you can directly create an instance of elephant in main or anywhere else in your program.
To refer to elephant, the code will have to give the fully qualified name, which is ABC::elephant.
int main() {
  // Create an elephant on the stack without creating an instance
  // of ABC:
  ABC::elephant my_elephant;

  // Create an elephant in dynamic memory with a smart pointer:
  auto my_heap_elephant_ptr = std::make_unique<ABC::elephant>();
}

// Use elephant as the type for a member variable of a different
// class or struct.
struct XYZ {
  ABC::elephant member_elephant_in_XYZ;
};


Just refer to the type as ABC::elephant.
But you have already created two instances. i.instance and i.a are both instances.

Actually, I could have phrased it correctly the first time, but what I meant to ask is whether there is a way to create an instance of the structure, similar to how the instance and a objects are created within the class?

ABC::elephant this_is_an_elephant; will do it.
